# Star dashboard for Oauth users

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I have asked this question on Grafana slack, community and on Reddit. Now time to try my luck here :)

We have integrated Grafana access via OAuth sign in. Users would be authorized by an external OAuth entity. What I want to do is to have a custom home page for these users. All of them should be able to see the available dashboards in the home page itself.

What I have found already is that, for the dashboards to appear on the home page, one needs to use the API to star it. I was able to do that using the REST API (/api/user/stars/dashboard/id) and using the admin credentials for basic auth, but that is valid only for that user i.e only the admin in this case can see the dashboards, not the OAuth users.

How can I make this (starring dashboards) global for all OAuth users ? The users are not known beforehand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you stick to this approach? Why you just don't create own home dashboard and then set it as home dashboard on the organization level. Own home dashboard can be fancy: logo in the `Text` panel, dashboard structure/classification created with `Dashboard list` panels (such as https://play.grafana.org), header, footer, ...

Comment: @JanGaraj Thanks a ton! That worked. If you put your comment as an answer, then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API approach will be complicated. Rather create own home dashboard and then set it as home dashboard on the organization level. Own home dashboard can be fancy: logo in the Text panel, dashboard structure/classification created with Dashboard list panels (such as play.grafana.org), header, footer, ...